# Density Hales-Jewett for product sets

Tags: co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

Let $k\geq 3$ and $A\subseteq[k]^n$ be a subset of density $\delta=|A|/k^n$. The density Hales-Jewett theorem states that if $\delta\geq1/\alpha(n)$, then $A$ must contain a combinatorial line, where $\alpha(n)$ is an inverse-Ackermann type slow-growing function.

Each element in $[k]^n$ can be viewed as a partition of $[n]$ into $k$ (possibly empty) parts. Now assume that $A$ is a product set w.r.t. the $k$ parts, that is, there exists $S_1,\ldots,S_k\subseteq2^{[n]}$ such that
$$A=\{x\in[k]^n\mid I_j(x)\in S_j,\ \forall j\in[k]\}, \textrm{ where } I_j(x)=\{i\in[n]\mid x_i=j\}$$
Is there a better bound on the density $\delta$ to guarantee the existence of a combinatorial line in $A$? In particular, even for $k=3$, is a polynomial in $n$ bound possible?

Note that the construction in [Polymath1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.0374.pdf), where the tuples $(|I_1(x)|,\ldots,|I_k(x)|)$ form a Fujimura set, does NOT result in a product set $A$.